# Flow which transforms List[A] into List[B] with flattening, given another Flow which transforms A to List[B]

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have an "inner" flow which transforms `A` into `List[B]`. I'd like to create a Flow which transforms `List[A]` into `List[B]` by invoking the "inner" flow on every element of each `List[A]` and then flattens the result.

For illustration, please see the test case below (the dependencies are the latest `scalatest` and `akka-stream`, `A` here is `String`, `B` here is `Char`, the "inner" flow is `stringToCharacters`).

The test passes, but the implementation is not idiomatic Akka Streams code since it materializes / runs the sub-streams.

Please suggest a better, idiomatic implementation which does not involve running the sub-streams.

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Sink, Source}
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.Matchers._
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures.whenReady
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class TestSpec extends FlatSpec {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  /* This is just for illustration and testing purposes, `flattenFlows` should support various inner flows */
  val stringToCharacters: Flow[String, List[Char], NotUsed] =
    Flow[String].map(x => x.toList)

  /* FIXME: I'm looking for a better implementation of the following function, please don't change the signature */
  def flattenFlows[A, B](innerFlow: Flow[A, List[B], NotUsed]): Flow[List[A], List[B], NotUsed] = {
    Flow[List[A]]
      .mapAsync(Int.MaxValue) { x =>
        Source(x).via(innerFlow).runWith(Sink.seq).map(_.flatten.toList)
      }
  }

  it should "flatten flows" in {
    val input = List(
      List("ab", "cd"),
      List("ef", "gh")
    )

    val result = Source(input).via(flattenFlows(stringToCharacters)).runWith(Sink.seq)

    val expected = List(
      List('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
      List('e', 'f', 'g', 'h')
    )

    whenReady(result) { x =>
      x.toList shouldEqual expected
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `mapConcat`?

Comment: `mapConcat` would help me if I had a function which transforms `A` to `List[B]` but I don't have a function, only a flow.

Comment: ".mapAsync(Int.MaxValue) { x =>" <--- you really want a buffer of 2 billion elements?

Comment: Absolutely not. This function is the one I'm looking to be rewritten in a better way. If you tell me that this just means going from `Int.MaxValue` to something smaller I'll take your word for it and just do that. But I was thinking there can be a different way altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of `flatMapConcat` and `fold`

```
  def flattenFlows[A, B](innerFlow: Flow[A, List[B], NotUsed]): Flow[List[A], List[B], NotUsed] =
    Flow[List[A]].flatMapConcat{ x => Source(x).via(innerFlow).fold(List.empty[B])(_ ::: _)}
```

Comment: The test is just illustrative of the problem. Your suggestion does not invoke `stringToCharacters` "inner" Flow. If my goal was just to get from `List[String]` to `List[Char]` I would of course do it like you suggest, but my actual problem is more complex.

Comment: Changed my answer by proposing `flatMapConcat`

Comment: This still solves a different problem than in the question (hence your change in the signature of `flattenFlows`). This assumes that I have a function `List[A] => A` available which may not be the case (and actually isn't available in my actual use case).

Comment: Edited my answer again, third iteration :)

Comment: OK, this works and looks better than what I have. Thanks!